# Как запустить бота на heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

Не получается запустить бота на Heroku. При запуске приложения вылазит Application Error.
Сам скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from time import sleep
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
import random


def start(bot, update):
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hello!")


def add_word(bot, update, args):
    file = open('file_name.txt', 'r')
    lines = [el.strip() for el in file.readlines()]
    file.close()
    t = 0
    with open('words.txt', 'a') as file:
        for el in args:
            if el not in lines:
                file.write(el)
                file.write('\n')
                t += 1
            else:
                bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='"%s" has already exist in a vocabulary' % el)

    file.close()

    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Added %d new words' % t)


def repeat_word(bot, update):

    file = open('file_name.txt', 'r')
    lines = [el.strip() for el in file.readlines()]
    file.close()

    if (len(lines) != 0):
        text_to_response = lambda: random.choice(lines)
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text = text_to_response())

    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text = 'Empty vocabulary') 

TOKEN = '....'
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN)

start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

add_word_handler = CommandHandler('add_word', add_word, pass_args = True)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(add_word_handler)

repeat_word_handler = CommandHandler('repeat_word', repeat_word)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(repeat_word_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

requirements.txt:

```
certifi==2018.4.16

chardet==3.0.4

future==0.16.0

idna==2.7

python-telegram-bot==10.1.0

requests==2.19.1

urllib3==1.23
```

Procfile:
    worker: python Bot.py

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы ты ему номер порта настраивал.

Comment: Не подскажите, как?
что-то вроди worker: python Bot.py 0.0.0.0:5000  ?

Comment: Тебе heroku через переменные среды должен передавать номер порта, на котором тебе надо запускать бота. На других он не даст.

Comment: текст ошибки как текст в вопрос добавьте, чтобы можно было бы конкретный ответ дать и помочь другим людям с той же проблемой найти решение.